# Angularjs, using data-ng-controller and ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

Sometimes I see `data-ng-controller` but more often `ng-controller`

The `ng-controller` I already have used and this seems clear. But `data-ng-controller`.. what is for?

What are the differences between them, and where to use what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Angularjs uses a normalization process for directive name / attributes matching.

From the angularjs docu at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Section Matching Directives:

> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
>   Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

Comment: Just a bit further down in the docs: 
Best Practice: Prefer using the dash-delimited format (e.g. ng-bind for ngBind). If you want to use an HTML validating tool, you can instead use the data-prefixed version (e.g. data-ng-bind for ngBind).

Answer (score 31):

There is no difference except for validation and browser compatibility.

Angular js will not work in IE8 unless data is present

[Update]

- The above is for versions 1.0.* and 1.2.*
- 1.3.* does not support ie8 so you don't need data-

Comment: SharePoint strips ng parameters off, so data-ng-* is still needed.

Answer (score 11):

There's no difference between the two, except that prefixing with `data-` will allow the HTML to pass validation.

Answer (score 1):

You may also see x-ng-controller.
Both data- and x- are html5 custom attribute naming compliant.