# Unable to access scope data in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

This is a line of code from Template 1 (the template displays a list of users). The controller for this is `MainCtrl`.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#configureUserModal" href="#" ng-click="getUserDetails(user.id)">{{user.name}}</a>

</div>

<modal-configure-user></modal-configure-user>
```

The relevant code in my `MainCtrl` is:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', '$timeout', function(
    $scope, $http, $window, $rootScope, $routeParams, $timeout) {

$scope.getUserDetails = function (userId) {
        $http.get("/user/" + userId).success(function(data) {
            $scope.userData=data[0];
            console.log($scope.userData.name); //Line 1
        });
};

}]);
```

Now Template 2 for individual users opens when the User Name in Template 1 is clicked. I just want to display the user name in Template 2, so I do:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="configureUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

{{userData.name}} //Line 2

</div>
```

The controller for Template 2 is also `MainCtrl`. But the problem is `Line 1` works (prints the user name to console), `Line 2` doesn't (it just shows up as null). I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Is it a timing issue? Is Template 2 loaded faster than the HTTP request?

Comment: This could be a scoping issue. Could you show your ng-controller declaration?

Comment: @pixelbits Have added that in.

Comment: Your second controller is out-of-scope.  Each ng-controller declaration will get its own new scope.  If you want to share data, use angular services instead.

Comment: you can check data-ng-controller and ng-controller  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567922/angularjs-using-data-ng-controller-and-ng-controller

Comment: @pixelbits Ah, that makes sense! Still getting the hang of this, so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ng-controller declaration will get its own instance of the controller, and $scope as well.  Changing the data on the scope for one ng-controller, will not impact the other.

If you want to share data, you should be using Angular services.  I am going to demonstrate how to use an Angular factory to share data, but you can just as easily implement a service too.

For the differences between a service vs factory, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory/25092033#25092033).

Angular services and factories are singletons, which means that the same instance is used everywhere that they are injected.  This makes it perfect for sharing data.

Here is how you could share data using a factory:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('userDetailService', function($http) {    
    var userData = {};
    function getUserDetails(userId) {
       return $http.get("/user/" + userId).success(function(data) {
           // copy is used to preserve the reference
           angular.copy(data[0], userData);
           console.log(userData.name);
        });
    }
    return {
        userData: userData,
        getUserDetails: getUserDetails
    }

});
```

Then you can call the userDetailService, and bind to userData in any of your controllers. Call getUserDetails() whenever you need to and all bindings to userData will automatically be updated.

```
// controller 1
app.controller('controller1', function($scope, userDetailService) {
    $scope.userData = userDetailService.userData;
    userDetailService.getUserDetails('johnsmith').success(function() {
          // success - do anything else here if you want
    });
});


// controller 2
app.controller('controller2', function($scope, userDetailService) {
    $scope.userData = userDetailService.userData;
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="controller1">
     {{userData.name}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="controller2">
     {{userData.name}}
</div>
```