# When should ng-controller be used vs. data-ng-controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-controller

With reference to [Angularjs, using data-ng-controller and ng-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567922/angularjs-using-data-ng-controller-and-ng-controller), how do I decide which to use?

In the present-day context, when should I use each one with regards to guidelines on good software design?

The referenced question mentions that data-ng-controller should be used to pass HTML validation. Is that still true, and how much should I be concerned with validation when my project does not explicitly require it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime html5 is not able to render custom tags such as ng controller, it doesn't makes any difference but it adds a marker that tells DOM to render this tag and not to throw error so better user pith prefix data-ng-controller